# Book recommendation for self study in Functional Analysis, Complex Analysis and Algebraic Topology

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, algebraic-topology, book-recommendation

I'm a first year graduate student in physics who picked up both an undergraduate degree in math and physics.  However, in getting the math degree there were a few courses I either didn't take or simply didn't feel I had learned to the fullest extent.  So, to remedy this I'm looking for some book recommendations on the following subjects:

1: Functional Analysis.  Never took this course and am looking for two types of books: a mathematical type text that may be done at say the third or fourth year undergraduate level, and a more physics applications oriented one.  For example covering Sobolev spaces.

2: Complex Analysis.  I only want to look into a more mathematical text for this one, and was thinking Ahlfors but am open to suggestion.

3: Algebraic Topology.  Self studied mostly from a collection of different sources and then Hatcher.  Was looking for a physics oriented text to go along with this.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't have strong preferences for 1. or 3... certainly Hatcher is fairly popular and not a bad choice. I just taught complex analysis last year and the top of my text list goes like:  Saff and Snider. Marsden, Gamelin, Alhfors, Albowitz and Fokas. The text by Saff and Snider is the most computational clear. It reads like a low-level calculus text in places. Gamelin has excellent insights and some deep work on green's functions, and Albowitz and Fokas has a lot of breadth. Alhfors influences all the others. I can't choose. I like them all.

Comment: For functional analysis, mathematical and at the 3rd to 4th year undergraduate, look at [**Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0471504599) by Erwin Kreyszig.

Comment: For functional analysis covering sobolev spaces you should certainly take a look at [Brezis' book](https://www.google.com.br/books/edition/Functional_Analysis_Sobolev_Spaces_and_P/GAA2XqOIIGoC?hl=pt-BR&gbpv=0).

Answer (score 0):

1: I would recommend 'Linear Functional Analysis' by Rynne and Youngson.  I'm not sure about the book by Kreyszig, as it seems like it goes off on a tangent quite a lot and gets a bit crazy in places.  For functional analysis with physics applications, see Barry Simon.

2: For complex analysis I'm not sure, I did study it but we had our own set of coursebooks from the university which were basically the only thing we used.  Maybe the book by Ian Stewart, but I haven't read it.

3: As you have a background in physics, I recommend 'Introduction to Topological Manifolds' by John Lee before Hatcher.  Maybe try Munkres if you find Hatcher not to your liking, as I believe the content is similar.  For physics, the book by Nash and Sen is well-known, although I must admit I haven't actually read it.

Answer (score 0):

Reed and Simon for functional analysis and Ahlfors for complex analysis. Munkres is good, but I didn't read the entire thing. Reed and Simon have four books in their mathematical physics series. It's worth checking out the others.

Answer (score 0):

"Functional Analysis: Introduction to Further Topics in Analysis"and also "complex analysis" by Elias M.Stein are very easy to read and self learn.

Answer (score -4):

I recommend this site for book recommendations:

https://bookauthority.org/